# Read foreach variable value outside the function

Tags: javascript, json, function

i have 2 functions where i have many variables stored . i want to read those variables outside the function as well. so i can read that value and apply if condition on that. please help.

And here are the functions,

```
var dynamicFormObject = new dynamicObject(jsonDataModel);

function dynamicObject(jsonData) {
  this.formId = jsonData[0].formName;
  console.log(this.formId);
  this.formType = jsonData[0].formType;
  this.formLayout = jsonData[0].formLayout;
  this.sectionCount = jsonData[0].sections.length;
  this.getSectionDetails = sectionDetails(jsonData[0].sections);
  this.formRows = getSetionFieldDetails(jsonData[0].sections);
  this.formFields = getContainedFields(jsonData[0].sections);
  this.getNoOfSections = function(jsonData) {
    return jsonData[0].sections.length;
  };
}


function sectionDetails(sectionData) {
  var sectionDetails = [];
  if (sectionData.length > 0) {
    sectionData.forEach(function(item) {
      sectionDetails.push({
        sectionId: item.sectionId,
        sectionName: item.sectionName,
        sectionLayout: item.sectionLayout
      });
    });

    return sectionDetails;
  } else {
    return "Error";
  }
}

sectionDetails(jsonDataModel);
console.log(sectionDetails[0].sectionLayout);

if($scope.entity[0].sections[0].sectionId === 1 && $scope.entity[0].sections[0].sectionLayout == "linear_layout_vertical"){
    if(dynamicFormObject.formLayout == "linear_layout_horizontal"){
        console.log("sadasd");
        var newdiv = document.createElement("div");
        console.log(newdiv);
        newdiv.setAttribute('horizontal', '');
        newdiv.setAttribute('layout', '');
        newdiv.className('col-md-12');
        document.body.appendChild(newdiv);

    }
```

Comment: when you show too much data, no one dares to help. At least I don't. Kindly reduce your data to minimum required .

Comment: Agreed, I refused to read wall of code. However if you introduced the problem accurately, the answer is below.

Comment: I have reduce the length of a code . tell me how to fetch this variable value outside function and foreach variable value as well

Comment: Which variables are you trying to fetch? The first function doesn't have any variables, it just sets properties of the object. You can access them with `dynamicFormObject.propertyName`. The second function has one variable `sectionDetails`, and it returns it to the caller, so it can use the return value.

Comment: @Barmar I want to fetch "sectionLayout" value in second function. How to do that ?

Comment: There's no such variable in the second function. Each element of `sectionData` and `sectionDetails` has a `sectionLayout` property. You can access that in the returned value.

Comment: @Barmar You mean like this?

console.log(sectionDetails.sectionLayout);

Comment: `sectionDetails` is an array, you have to index it.

Comment: `sectionDetails[0].sectionLayout`, `sectionDetails[1].sectionLayout`, etc. Which one are you trying to fetch? Why just that one?

Comment: I think you should post some code that shows what you're really trying to do.

Comment: I am trying to fetch all sections from JSON so i can dynamically create sections in HTML based on sectionId and sectionLayout.

Comment: @Barmar Now check the code.  You will come to know what i am trying to do

Comment: You need to assign the return value of `sectionDetails(jsonDataModel)` to another variable, then index that.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to access a variable declared from within a function closure from outside it's function closure, however, you can declare a variable outside the function and only use/update it within the function, and the results of that use/update will be available outside the function.

```
var x;

function setX(){
  x = 6;
}

setX();

console.log(x) // 6
```